# Activation mail account nodejs mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, email

- Hello, I have a small problem with the activation of the registered account via link that is send on an email.
- At the moment when I receive the link on my mailbox, I click on the link and I have this error

  > Cannot POST /confirmation/26169e36df56653301407316a89589e1
- Could you change the code so that it works. Thank you your helpers.

My app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var config = require('./config/database');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ajax');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');



var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(expressValidator());


app.use('/', require('./routes/activationRoutes'));


module.exports = app;
```

My activationRoutes.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var crypto = require('crypto');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');


const bluebird = require('bluebird');



var User = require('../models/User');
var Token = require('../models/Token');


router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.assert('email', 'Email cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.assert('password', 'Password cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ remove_dots: false });

    // Check for validation erro
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) return res.status(400).send(errors);

    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'The email address ' + req.body.email + ' is not associated with any account. Double-check your email address and try again.'});

        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, function (err, isMatch) {
            if (!isMatch) return res.status(401).send({ msg: 'Invalid email or password' });

            // Make sure the user has been verified
            if (!user.isVerified) return res.status(401).send({ type: 'not-verified', msg: 'Your account has not been verified.' });

            // Login successful, write token, and send back user
            res.send({ token: generateToken(user), user: user.toJSON() });
        });
    });
});




router.post('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('name', 'Name cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.assert('email', 'Email cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.assert('password', 'Password must be at least 4 characters long').len(4);
    req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ remove_dots: false });

    // Check for validation errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) { return res.status(400).send(errors); }

    // Make sure this account doesn't already exist
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function (err, user) {

        // Make sure user doesn't already exist
        if (user) return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'The email address you have entered is already associated with another account.' });

        // Create and save the user
        user = new User({ name: req.body.name, email: req.body.email, password: req.body.password });
        user.save(function (err) {
            if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }

            // Create a verification token for this user
            var token = new Token({ _userId: user._id, token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex') });

            // Save the verification token
            token.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }

                // Send the email
                var sender = nodemailer.createTransport({
                    service: 'gmail',
                    auth: {
                        user: 'votreMAIL@gmail.com',
                        pass: 'votrePASSWORD'
                    }
                });
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: 'votreMAIL@gmail.com',
                    to: user.email,
                    subject: 'Account Verification Token',
                    text: 'Hello,\n\n' + 'Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp:\/\/' + req.headers.host + '\/confirmation\/' + token.token + '.\n'
                };
                sender.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                    if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                    res.status(200).send('A verification email has been sent to ' + user.email + '.');
                });
            });
        });
    });
});




router.post('/confirmation', function(req, res, next) {
    req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.assert('email', 'Email cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.assert('token', 'Token cannot be blank').notEmpty();
    req.sanitize('email').normalizeEmail({ remove_dots: false });

    // Check for validation errors
    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) return res.status(400).send(errors);

    // Find a matching token
    Token.findOne({ token: req.body.token }, function (err, token) {
        console.log(req.body.token);
        if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ type: 'not-verified', msg: 'We were unable to find a valid token. Your token my have expired.' });

        // If we found a token, find a matching user
        User.findOne({ _id: token._userId }, function (err, user) {
            if (!user) return res.status(400).send({ msg: 'We were unable to find a user for this token.' });
            if (user.isVerified) return res.status(400).send({ type: 'already-verified', msg: 'This user has already been verified.' });

            // Verify and save the user
            user.isVerified = true;
            user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) { return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message }); }
                res.status(200).send("The account has been verified. Please log in.");
            });
        });
    });
});




module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Yes of course, it's changed

Comment: you define `route.post('/confirmation')` but you call a GET, change it to `route.get('/confirmation')`

Comment: I also test with the get, it does not work

Comment: You are missing the param in the route: `'/confirmation/:confId'`. It wouldn't help that much though, because the controller expects the id in the request body, not param. Looks like you're missing the route entirely.